# reledpar: remove unused space for line numbers

Tags: reledpar

I want so set an original text and its translation in parallel columns without any line or paragraph numbering.

The texts are from an older project, each part is in its own file and is included via input command. I don't want to spend any work on rearrange it. The reledpar package reached this aim at best.

At least there is one problem: When I suppress the line numbering with the \numberlinefalse command, there is still the white space for the numbers. How can I remove this 'additional left margin'? Reledpar v.2.9.0 and reledmac v.2.10.0 are used.

Here is the example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,parskip=no]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[russian,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{microtype}% better typesetting
\usepackage[%
    widthliketwocolumns,
    nocritical,
    noeledsec,
    noend,
    nofamiliar,
    noledgroup,
    series={}
    ]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}%[shiftedpstarts]

\setlength{\Lcolwidth}{.475\textwidth}
\setlength{\Rcolwidth}{.375\textwidth}
\numberlinefalse

\newcommand{\briefseite}[2]{%
    \begin{pairs}%
        \begin{Leftside}%
            \begingroup
            \beginnumbering%
                \par
                \autopar
                #1
                \par
            \endnumbering%
            \endgroup
        \end{Leftside}%
        \begin{otherlanguage}{russian}%
            \begin{Rightside}%
                \begingroup
                \beginnumbering%
                    \par
                    \autopar
                    #2
                    \par
                \endnumbering%
                \endgroup
            \end{Rightside}%
        \end{otherlanguage}%
    \par%
    \end{pairs}%
    \Columns%
}

\title{Der Dokumenttitel}
\author{Der Autorname}
\date{2016-00-00}


\begin{document}

Text über die komplette Breite. Text über die komplette Breite. Text    über die komplette Breite. Text über die komplette Breite.

\briefseite{%
    Deutscher Text auf der linken Seite. Deutscher Text auf der linken Seite. Deutscher Text auf der linken Seite.

    Deutscher Text auf der linken Seite. Deutscher Text auf der linken Seite. Deutscher Text auf der linken Seite.
}{%
    Русский текст на правой стороне. Русский текст на правой стороне. Русский текст на правой стороне.

    Русский текст на правой стороне. Русский текст на правой стороне. Русский текст на правой стороне.
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not directly related to the line number typesetting, but to the way the column are positionned on the page. Read § 4.2 of the reledpar handbook and / or look on the file `4-reledpar_columns_alignment.tex` on the example folders.

In your case, your MWE could become

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,parskip=no]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[russian,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{microtype}% better typesetting
\usepackage[%
    widthliketwocolumns,
    nocritical,
    noeledsec,
    noend,
    nofamiliar,
    noledgroup,
    series={}
    ]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}%[shiftedpstarts]

\setlength{\Lcolwidth}{.475\textwidth}
\setlength{\Rcolwidth}{.375\textwidth}
\columnsposition{C}
\setlength{\beforecolumnseparator}{0.075\textwidth}
\setlength{\aftercolumnseparator}{0.075\textwidth}
\AtBeginPairs{\sloppy}

%\numberlinefalse

\newcommand{\briefseite}[2]{%
    \begin{pairs}%
        \begin{Leftside}%
            \begingroup
            \beginnumbering%
                \par
                \autopar
                #1
                \par
            \endnumbering%
            \endgroup
        \end{Leftside}%
        \begin{otherlanguage}{russian}%
            \begin{Rightside}%
                \begingroup
                \beginnumbering%
                    \par
                    \autopar
                    #2
                    \par
                \endnumbering%
                \endgroup
            \end{Rightside}%
        \end{otherlanguage}%
    \par%
    \end{pairs}%
    \Columns%
}

\title{Der Dokumenttitel}
\author{Der Autorname}
\date{2016-00-00}


\begin{document}

Text über die komplette Breite. Text über die komplette Breite. Text    über die komplette Breite. Text über die komplette Breite.

\briefseite{%
    Deutscher Text auf der linken Seite. Deutscher Text auf der linken Seite. Deutscher Text auf der linken Seite.

    Deutscher Text auf der linken Seite. Deutscher Text auf der linken Seite. Deutscher Text auf der linken Seite.
}{%
    Русский текст на правой стороне. Русский текст на правой стороне. Русский текст на правой стороне.

    Русский текст на правой стороне. Русский текст на правой стороне. Русский текст на правой стороне.
}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, `\Lcolwidth+\Rcolwidth+\beforecolumnseparator+\aftercolumnseparator=\textwidth`.

I have also added `\AtBeginPairs{\sloppy}` which prevent overfull hbox in column parallel typesetting, even if with a bad typographical grey.

Ps: I was not able to see the russian characters in the final output…